# Need help in Cross Joins

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR 
     FROM 
         INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL 
     WHERE 
         CONSOL_KEY10 = 'CUR' 
     GROUP BY 
         Consol_Key10

     CROSS JOIN

     SELECT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR 
     FROM 
         INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL 
     WHERE 
         CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('REG','WCL') 
     GROUP BY 
         Consol_Key10

     CROSS JOIN

     SELECT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR 
     FROM 
         INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL 
     WHERE 
         CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('OAM', 'SUB') 
     GROUP BY 
         Consol_Key10

     CROSS JOIN

     SELECT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR 
     FROM 
         INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL 
     WHERE 
         CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('DBT', 'LOS') 
     GROUP BY 
         Consol_Key10

     CROSS JOIN

     SELECT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR 
     FROM 
         INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL 
     WHERE 
         CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('CHO') 
     GROUP BY 
         Consol_Key10
)
```

I'm getting these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Take smaller steps. Create one small query with one single cross join. Then take the next step.

Comment: How many columns and rows do you expect to have in your output?

Comment: You have 5 columns, all called `DR`, containing various different values. How are you intending to *access* this data when there's no means to distinguish which result came from each query?

Comment: I'd try UNION ALL instead of CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias and paranthesis for each subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 = 'CUR' GROUP BY Consol_Key10) AS t1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('REG','WCL') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) AS t2
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('OAM','SUB') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) AS t3
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('DBT','LOS') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) AS t4
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('CHO') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) AS t5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries belong in parentheses. Most DBMS also require names for them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR
   FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 = 'CUR' GROUP BY Consol_Key10) q1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR
   FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('REG','WCL') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) q2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR
   FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('OAM','SUB') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) q3
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR
   FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('DBT','LOS') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) q4
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT < 0 THEN LOCAL_CCY_AMT END) AS DR
   FROM INSIGHTSOURCE.BS.RE_CRF_GL WHERE CONSOL_KEY10 IN ('CHO') GROUP BY Consol_Key10) q5;
```